# Equilibrium from linear to quadratic

Tags: quadratics

I have this:

$Qd = 21 − 6P$

$Qs =−6+30(P − 0.9)$

I'm asked to solve P and Q at equilibrium.

If I'm not mistaken, $P=1,5$ (because $21 - 6P = -6 + 30P - 27$)

And Q is: $21 - 6*1.5 = 12$

I hope it's right.

Now the tricky part is to determine the quadratic formula that expresses the equilibrium price and quantity as a function of τ (where τ is 0.9 here above) . Subsequently, I should express the revenue as a function of τ

I'm given 4 possible answers for the revenues and I have to pick one:

(a) $18τ−6.667τ^2$

(b) $16.5τ−5τ^2$

(c) $15τ−3.333τ^2$

(d) $13.8τ−2τ^2$

They all give the same right prediction (10.8) with $τ=0.9$ of course, which doesn't help.

But I don't know how to go from two linear equations to a quadratic one.

What I tried is this:

if $-6 + 30(P-τ) = 12$

Then $-6 + 30(P-τ) = 13.33333*0.9 = 13.33333τ$

Then, I just multiplied both sides by τ (for whatever reason, in order to have a $τ^2$ to toy with):

$-6τ + 30τ(P-τ) = 13.33333τ^2$

And (considering that $P=1.5$), I get:

$39τ - 16,666666τ^2$

But none of the formulas proposed here above are matching it (and my answer can't be reduced into any of these).

I'm probably couldn't be more wrong but that's what I get when messing around with those equations.

I looked on the internet but either I find linear or quadratic examples. None that goes from one to another.
And to me it even make sense that nothing is to be found. I don't know why there should be any reason to go from one to another. It's like apple and oranges to me.
Obviously there is something that I just don't get.

Any help please?

Thanks!

Comment: Here's a guide to [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I made the changes. Thanks. Any help regarding my question, maybe?

Comment: Is there something wrong with the question? Is it unclear? English is not my native language but I can try to make it better if needed.

Comment: I'm not the right person to answer. I know calculus, but I haven't learnt it in the context of economics. You can try to add a [bounty](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/bounty), but as the minimum bounty is 50 reputation, you might need to gain more reputation first.